# Debugging big plugins in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, plugins

I want to debug agilereview plugin, which I download from here:

https://github.com/AgileReview-Project/AgileReview-EclipsePlugin

But I have no idea, how to debug this big plugin which has many plugin projects. From where should I start? For example, from which projects? There are many plugin projects:

```
org.agilereview.common
org.agilereview.core
org.agilereview.storage
org.agilereview.export
org.agilereview.test
```

I am not finding any main method, which is the problem. Another problem could be, I don't know how to debug such big plugins. I am new in eclipse plugin development and debugging.

Comment: You have to run plugins as part of a full Eclipse install, you can't run them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Start your application in debug mode. *As long as no Bug occurs, there is nothing to debug.*

If an Exception occurs in your console, jump into the line where it happened. Find out what the Exception means and work up along the stack-trace to find the cause of the problem.

If a (non-Exception-) logical error occurs, add a break point where the problem appears (i.e. in the view or console-printer). Restart the application. When it stops at the break point, work up along the stack trace again.

You have an inherent problem in your question: you assume that it is a good idea, to work from the *entry point* of your application, down to the bug. But eclipse plugins have more than one entry point (called *extension points*). Instead using the Bug as a starting point for your research and work towards an entry point is the better approach. This is also true for non-plugin applications with only one entry point.

In some cases it makes sense to work top-down, instead of bottom-up: e.g. if a Button-Click doesn't trigger anything. Then you start at the `onClick` method of the button and work yourself down though the code, to see why nothing is triggered.

Comment: In this reply I assumed, that you know how to use a debugger. In case you don't know what your Debugger can do, you should learn those basics first.